# Traits UI: logarithmic range editor

Tags: python, user-interface, traitsui

I'm writing a graphical interface for with Traits UI in python, and I wonder if there is a simple way to make a [`RangeEditor`](http://docs.enthought.com/traitsui/traitsui_user_manual/factories_basic.html#rangeeditor) behave logarithmically, i.e. to make it's "internal" scale logarithmic, but still set the actual value of the trait. I can get closer by using the editor for an auxiliary trait `v`, and use `10**v` as the real value in the calculations, but this has the inconvenience that the text box shows the auxiliary trait and not the actual one.

If this is not possible out of the box and someone can help me designing a custom editor, I'd appreciate.

EDIT: There is actually an undocumented `mode='logslider'` option for `RangeEditor`, it seems to do what I need.